# How to organize these several lists of booleans to avoid code duplication?

Tags: java

My class `Person` has a number of boolean values: `isMoving`, `hasEyesOpen`, `isTired` etc. They are all independent and eight in total. These values are updated from elsewhere every second. The Person stores the last hundred historical values. My code seems to contain a lot of duplication. Is there a better way to write this class?

The main reason that I think this is bad code is that any new boolean must be added in a lot of places.

```
class Person {
    protected ArrayList<Boolean> histIsMoving = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
    protected ArrayList<Boolean> histHasEyesOpen = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
    protected ArrayList<Boolean> histIsTired = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
    // and 5 more ...

    public boolean getIsMoving() {
        return histIsMoving.get( histIsMoving.size()-1 );
    }
    public boolean getHasEyesOpen() {
        return histHasEyesOpen.get( histHasEyesOpen.size()-1 );
    }
    public boolean getIsTired() {
        return histIsTired.get( histIsTired.size()-1 );
    }
    // and 5 more ...

    public ArrayList<Boolean> getHistIsMoving() {
        return histIsMoving;
    }
    public ArrayList<Boolean> getHistHasEyesOpen() {
        return histHasEyesOpen;
    }
    public ArrayList<Boolean> getHistIsTired() {
        return histIsTired;
    }
    // and 5 more ...

    public function update( boolean newIsMoving, boolean newHasEyesOpen, 
                            boolean newIsTired ) {
        histIsMoving.add( newIsMoving );
        histHasEyesOpen.add( newHasEyesOpen );
        histIsTired.add( newIsTired );
        // and 5 more arguments
    }
}
```

Comment: @NarendraPathai I'm not really asking how my code is, but how this kind of problem should be solved. I just supplied my code in order to show some research effort and motivate the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well one way to do it is to create a class 'PersonProperty'. You could make it a generic class if you intend to have non-boolean properties in the Person.

The PersonProperty class could have methods getValue(), setValue(), getHistory() and a way of being identified - e.g. getName() that returns 'isTired', 'hasEyes', etc. as string values.

Your Person class could then keep a hashmap container that maps names to 'PersonProperty' objects and methods along the lines of 'getPropertyValue(String propertyName)', 'getPropertyNames()', 'updatePropertyValue(String name, boolean value)'

```
class PersonProperty {

    private ArrayList<Boolean> history = new ArrayList(100);
    private boolean value;
    private String name;

    PersonProperty(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public boolean getValue() { return value; }
    public String getName() { return name; }
    public List<Boolean> getHistory() { return Collections.unmodifiableList(history); } 
    public void setValue(boolean value) { 
        // change value, add to history, make sure history is 100 elements at most
        // a queue container would be more appropriate here by the way
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a neat idea!

Comment: How would you make this "generic" to allow for both booleans and doubles, for instance? By replacing all `boolean` with `Object`?

Comment: No, I would declare it as a generic class - PersonProperty<T> - and replace all boolean with T - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/

Comment: Would it be possible to make a HashMap of such PersonProperties?